# Nock "no match for request" with regex

Tags: nock

I'm having a problem to mock a HTTP request from my Node.js code using nock.
To make the request I'm using the axios library:

```js
axios.get(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${id}/information?apiKey=${process.env.MY_SPOONACULAR_KEY}`);
```

*id* is just an integer like 1131030.

I'm using nock this way:

```js
nock('https://api.spoonacular.com')
    .persist()
    .log(console.log)
    .get('/recipes\/\d*\/information$/')
    .query(true)
    .reply(200, {answer: 'any'});
```

I'm using *query(true)* to match any query string. The regex in the *get* is to match any possible id on the request.

However it is not working, and from the nock log I'm getting the following:

> matching https://api.spoonacular.com:443/recipes/1131030/information to GET https://api.spoonacular.com:443/recipes/d*/information$/: false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a string, not a regex, to the `.get()` method. You need to remove the quotes.

```
.get(/recipes\/\d*\/information$/)
```

Also, using `.log()` is not preferred to when trying to figure out why Nock is not matching. Use DEBUG instead to get more information. https://github.com/nock/nock#debugging